# Given a function $f(x)$, determine if the following function is even, odd, or neither

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given a function $f(x)$, determine if the following function is even, odd, or neither:
$g(x) = −2[f(x)+f(−x)]$

I understand that a function is even if $f(-x) = f(x)$ is even, and odd if $f(-x) = -f(x)$, I'm just curious as to how it applies to something like this.

Comment: See if $g(-x)$ is $g(x)$ or $-g(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$g(x)=-2[f(x)+f(-x)]$$

Now we know that
$$g(-x)=-2[f(-x)+f(-(-x))] \\ =-2[f(-x)+f(x)]$$

Notice, however that $$f(x)+f(-x)=f(-x)+f(x)$$

Thus we can conclude that $$g(x)=g(-x)$$
Hence, out function is even.

Comment: I think you mean something other than odd..

Comment: Haha! Yes, sorry... I thought even but typed odd (it's still very early in the morning here and I just woke up). LOL! Thanks! :P

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

$$g(x) = -2(f(x)+f(-x)).$$

Then

$$g(-x) = -2(f(-x)+f(-(-x))).$$

What can you say about $f(-(-x))$? Can you take it from here?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's because I've been studying for 9 hours straight or what but why were you able to change the -2 to -1/2?

Comment: Oh silly me. *My* brain messed things up!